# tip display script cannot reset to default content

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to display a block of text in a td after mouseover event, however I aim to reset, i.e display oringinal content of the td on mouseout/mouseleave the code i used is as follow. pls help
I get an undefined error when the code is run. i think the problem is seeting the event to element variable.

```html
  
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
<!--
var content=new Array()
content[0]='Menus first'
content[1]='Menu Second'
content[2]='Menu Third'

function changetext(whichcontent){
document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML=whichcontent
}

function reset(){
if (!scriptmenu.contains(event.toElement))
descriptions.innerHTML=temphtml;

}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="scriptmenu" onmouseleave="reset()">
          <p><a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[0])" >Menu First</a><br>
            <a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[1])">Menu Second</a><br>
            <a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[2])">Menu Third</a><br>
          </p>
        </div></td>
      <td><div id="descriptions" align="left">
          <p><b>Welcome</b><br>
            Enjoy!<br>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

if (document.all)

var temphtml=descriptions.innerHTML;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are directly trying to set innerHTML on "descriptions" in reset() and inside if condition. Call this instead document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example. add `onmouseout` with every `onmouseover`
Other change to focus on

```
var defaultData = document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML;
function reset(){
if (!scriptmenu.contains(event.toElement))
descriptions.innerHTML=defaultData;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
<!--
var content=new Array()
content[0]='Menus first'
content[1]='Menu Second'
content[2]='Menu Third'

function changetext(whichcontent){
document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML=whichcontent
}


//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="400" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div id="scriptmenu" >
          <p><a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[0])" onmouseleave="reset()">Menu First</a><br>
            <a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[1])" onmouseleave="reset()">Menu Second</a><br>
            <a href="index.html" onMouseover="changetext(content[2])" onmouseleave="reset()">Menu Third</a><br>
          </p>
        </div></td>
      <td><div id="descriptions" align="left">
          <p><b>Welcome</b><br>
            Enjoy!<br>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
var defaultData = document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML;
function reset(){
if (!scriptmenu.contains(event.toElement))
descriptions.innerHTML=defaultData;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for our answer. This works fine here, however after copying to my system, it does not, even the mouseover failed. I got this error from chrome console...Uncaught ReferenceError: changetext is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onmouseover

Comment: There must be a typo ... Please verify your code ... Check for every anchor, when you use anchor in. JavaScript